# Java - Class Data Type - Sorting Problems

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, comparable

Assume that I have implemented a class Edge which has 4 attributes, all of which are of type int: `from` `to` `quality` `length`.

In my program , I have created an `Edge[]` array.

I want to Implement 2 Sorting Parameters -

One of them will sort the Edge array in descending order of the `qualities`,

The other will sort based on increasing order of `lengths`.

I will be needing these two orderings in distinct parts of my code.

I will be using the library function `Arrays.sort()` for sorting.

The only way I know of sorting Class Data Type Arrays to implement `compareTo()` within the class Edge but this only works for one parameter(quality or length but not both).

How can I implement two sorting functions(2 `compareTo()` functions ?) and decide which one to be called during sorting? In C++ , we can make many compare functions and simply state the function to go through.How to achieve this in Java?

Note: My goal is to sort an array of DataType Edge using `Arrays.sort()` , and use two different parameters for sorting and DECIDE which one is to be used at which point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you can create 2 classes that implements `Comparator`, defining your `compare` method, one for each of your sort orders you desire.

Then you can pass an instance of one of those `Comparator`s to `Arrays.sort`.

If you're using Java 8, you can pass a method reference to [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) to construct a `Comparator` based on a getter method.

```
Comparator<Edge> lengthAscEdgeComp = Comparator.comparing(Edge::getLength);
```

To make a descending sort, you can call [`reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--).

```
Comparator<Edge> qualityDescEdgeComp = Comparator.comparing(Edge::getQuality).reversed();
```

Answer (score 2):

You create two separate `Comparator` implementations that perform the algorithms you describe.  Then you can pass the appropriate instance to `Collections.sort`.

```
public class EdgeCompareLength implements Comparator<Edge>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Edge o1, Edge o2) {
        // your implementation here
        return 0;
    }
}

public class EdgeCompareProperties implements Comparator<Edge>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Edge o1, Edge o2) {
        // your implementation here
        return 0;
    }
}
```

So someplace you would have

```
List<Edge> edges = getEdges();

Collections.sort(edges,new EdgeCompareLength());
List<Edge> moreEdges = getMoreEdges();
Collections.sort(edges,new EdgeCompareProperties();
```

Comment: Could you provide some code to implement this? How would we select which one to use?

Comment: You would select the appropriate comparator implementation based on whatever you wanted.  How did you plan on selected when to sort?

Comment: Last Question: What if I wanted to sort a range in the array using these comparators. Arrays.sort(arr,N,M) sorts array arr from N to M(exc) according the properties.Can i do sth like Collections.sort(edges,new EdgeCompareLength(),N,M); or sth?

Comment: `Collections` doesn't have a ranged sort.  You'd have to use `Arrays.sort(T[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, Comparator<? super T> c)` and pass the appropriate comparator implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement the two sort orders (or at least one of them) by implementing `Comparator<Edge>`.  You then sort via the version of `Arrays.sort()` that accepts a `Comparator` as a second parameter.

Do not confuse that with having `Edge` itself implement the `Comparable` interface.  The `Comparator` implementations will be different classes (from `Edge` and from each other).

Example:

```
public class DescendingByQuality implements Comparator<Edge> {
    public int compare(Edge e1, Edge e2) {
        if (e1.getQuality() < e2.getQuality()) return 1;
        if (e1.getQuality() > e2.getQuality()) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}

...

Edge[] edges = ...;

Arrays.sort(edges, new DescendingByQuality());
```